# GTA SA not opening after installing MMGE 3.0

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

My gta sa does not open after installing mmge 3.0. In fact, I can't open gta sa after installing any kind of ENB. No error is shown. I am on Windows 10. Tried changing settings in Data Execution Prevention (DEP) but not of any use.

Comment: Is there no forum for this mod where you could ask this question? Not to shoot down your hopes, but finding somebody here, who plays San Andreas, uses this mod and knows what do with this problem seems fairly unlikely to me. The best idea I can offer you: uninstall compeltely, then reinstall and meticously follow the installation guide the author provides. Older games with no native mod support are very picky, especially on a modern OS like Win10. Doing anything different from the guide may cause the game to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should ask on the [development thread at GTAForums](http://gtaforums.com/topic/736359-enb-mmge/).

Also remember to read the FAQ on the mod page:

- Partial **incompatibility with Windows 8/8.1**. Possible fix which works for 50% of users is using modloader: install ENB as usual and move d3d9.dll, enbseries.ini and enblocal.ini to GTASA\modloader\enb\ folder, the rest stays where it is.
- If your game doesn't start, reinstall DX setup from GTASA disk or use [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35).

Also I recommend installing [SilentPatch](http://gtaforums.com/topic/669045-silentpatch/), a bug-fixing mod that works as expected (it also removes the requirement of DEP or Data Execution Prevention).